# How to unset the main array if an item in sub array is removed?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, session

I want to unset the main array (orders)  if any `[type] => main` is deleted and delete only the sub array if `[type] => addon` is deleted. Addons are additional items that comes with main product while ordering.If main product is deleted main product and its addon (Main array will be deleted) and if customer dont want addon they can remove it from cart.

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Heart Choclates
        [code] => LFB-P-10
        [qty] => 1
        [type] => main
        [price] => 1200
        [stock] => 1
        [image] => choclates-valentines-day.jpg
        [quantity] => 12
        [expdate] => Jun 02nd 2017
        [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM
        [expdtype] => Fixed time delivery
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Birthday Pink
        [code] => KB-P-5
        [qty] => 1
        [type] => addon
        [price] => 600
        [stock] => 3
        [image] => pink-roses.jpg
        [expdate] => Jun 02nd 2017
        [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM
        [expdtype] => Fixed time delivery
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Red & Yellow Roses
        [code] => KB-P-6
        [qty] => 1
        [type] => main
        [price] => 800
        [stock] => 8
        [image] => birthday-red-roses.jpg
        [expdate] => Jun 15th 2017
        [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 12:00 PM
        [expdtype] => Standard delivery
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Truffle Cake
        [code] => KB-P-8
        [qty] => 1
        [type] => addon
        [price] => 10
        [stock] => 3
        [image] => truffle-cake.jpg
        [expdate] => Jun 15th 2017
        [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 12:00 PM
        [expdtype] => Standard delivery
        )
    )
```

This is how my code looks like.

```
if (isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
        $product_code = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
        $product_type = $_GET["removet"]; //get the product type to remove
        $return_url   = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url
        if (isset($_SESSION["grand_total"])) {
            unset($_SESSION['grand_total']);
        }
        $array = $_SESSION["products"];
        print_r($array);
        foreach($array as $key => $sub_array) {
            foreach($sub_array as $innerRow => $cart_itm){
                if($cart_itm['type'] == $product_type && $cart_itm['code'] == $product_code) {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                    break; //if there will be only one then break out of loop
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried this but it didn't work.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether `$product_type` is `main` or `addon` and do different deletions.

```
foreach($array as $key => $sub_array) {
    foreach($sub_array as $innerRow => $cart_itm){
        if($cart_itm['type'] == $product_type && $cart_itm['code'] == $product_code) {
            if ($product_type == 'main') {
                unset($array[$key]);
                break; //if there will be only one then break out of loop
            } elseif ($product_type == 'addon') {
                unset($array[$key][$innerRow]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/nm8dyR)

Comment: Yes it worked the mistake was i didn't save the array to session. $_SESSION["products"]  =$array; Like this. so it didn't reflect on my cart. Thank you soo much

Comment: Hey is there any way i can update [qty] => 1 field without using array merge

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Update it with what?

Comment: How can i increase the quantity of products in this array ? Do i need to use array_merge function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307577/updating-a-value-in-an-array-using-php

Comment: `$array[$key][$innerRow]['qty']++`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145682/discussion-between-sarath-hari-and-barmar).